# Update webpage after receiving POST request

Tags: php, python, http-post

I've to tried to find out similar issue in stack overflow, but I couldn't. I am using python requests library to send POST request to my personal domain name www.****.com.

```
r = requests.post('http://www.****.com', data = {'temp1':"Anum"})
print r.text
```

When I run the script, the r.text shows me "Welcome Anum". Where I have written a small php script on my website

```
<?php
      $data=$_POST["temp1"];
      echo "Welcome ". $data. "<br />";
?>
```

Now the problem is, I am not able to see this get request on actual website, even after refreshing the page. I tried sending POST request in a loop after every 3 seconds, but still can't see any update on actual website. Do I need to loop up my php code to continuously listen for requests from client ? 
My understanding is that my domain name is working as Server and python script as client, so as the client send request to server, how do I manage my server to catch that request and display on web page ?

Comment: no. php doesn' "listen" for requests, unless you explicitly set it up to run as a webserver. your WEBSERVER listens for the requests, and then runs the PHP code when a request does come in.

Comment: on the html form - what action have you got i.e. <form name='f1' method='post' action='myPage.php'>

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want the python script to send a variable, which will be visible to other visitors of the website?
You need to store the value which you recieve from python somewhere, like in a database. Then you can read that value and show it to the visitor.

Comment: Yes I've managed to do it that way, but can't I do it like without database ? any possibility ?

Comment: There are loads of other methods to store a variable. Save it to a file, in memcached/apc, etc

Comment: Now I am storing the POST values in the database, but the problem is, I have to refresh the page manually to see the updated value on web-page. I need the page to auto-refresh (or something like ajax), to update the value on page, as new POST value is received.