# PHP - How to display POST data received in a HTML page

Tags: php, fetch-api

I have a simple HTML page (let's call it Page H) and it's hosted on a remote server. This page has been configured to allow for cross-origin requests.

Now, I would like to do the following:

1. From localhost (or otherwise), use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send a POST request containing some data to Page H
2. Upon receiving the POST request, the HTML page should display the information sent in the POST request

The page is really simple right now, with only HTML and some basic PHP. Is there a way to accomplish what I want without involving a database? I saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999552/update-webpage-after-receiving-post-request) but the answer is not quite satisfactory...

Edit:

The basic HTML (which is hosted on a remote server):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head> 
<body> 
    <h1>Hello World!</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The `Fetch API` request (sent from some other random place, like my own computer):

```
fetch('./test.txt') // getting data from a text file
  .then(function(response){
    return response.text(); 
  })
  .then(function(data){ 
    console.log(data); 

  fetch('<WEBSITE_FOR_HTML_PAGE>', { 
   method: 'POST',
   body: data
  })
  .then(function (response) { // I don't care about the response
  })  
  .catch(function (error) {  
   console.log('Request failure: ', error);  
  });
  })
```

So I want the HTML page to display the data sent using the `Fetch API`...

Comment: use `Ajax` for request, response and render response.

Comment: if you have simple html but inclusion of PHP code you can display request received using. You can able to see output wherever you are sending API request. Database connection is not required in such case. If thinking if call API and if someone is seeing this will manipulate view of users. then no !

Comment: @urfusion thanks for the comment, but do you mean to use Ajax to make the request as well? Note that the request has to be made using Fetch API (I'm testing something), and is not being done by the HTML page itself (but another source)...

Comment: @aviboy2006 What can I display the request received using? You seemed to have missed out the keyword which I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: can you share sample command or postman request what you need. You will received response in html+php file var_dump($_POST)

Comment: If this html file can it be .php file then everything will get solve. You need to avoid only database connectivity right ?

Comment: Page will not display anything only you will received in API response. You are using this as API communication bridge.

Comment: HTML is a static document. Where do you store the information?

Comment: @Dharman I am not storing the information anywhere at the moment. My main question is really whether I can dynamically update html when I get a POST request without having to store anything :/

Comment: No, you can't. HTML is just a text document. It is not a program. If you want to develop such functionality you need to use a backend language like PHP and develop a piece of code to store the values somewhere.

Comment: @Dharman I see, alright then! thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function to print the [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) [superglobal variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it does not update the HTML page. Correct me if I am wrong, but you  would just include this as part of the PHP in the HTML page, right?

Comment: You'll get the POST variable returned in `response` of the AJAX request. Try `console.log()` the response